# How can I transpose a vertical 2 column list to a horizontal list, keeping the groupings, in excel?

Tags: excel, function, match

I have a data set of countries and each country has a specific list of "things", like "shifts" for example, but to keep this simple, let's just say we have Makes of Cars with a couple of Models of Car, for each make, like this:

| Make | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Honda | Accord |
| Honda | Civic |
| Toyota | Camry |
| Toyota | Tundra |

I want convert the above data set, which I'm referring to as "vertical", into a "horizontal" listings...as follows:

| Honda | Toyota |
| --- | --- |
| Accord | Camry |
| Civic | Tundra |

I think I can do this with a combination of functions, maybe with a Match and an Offset but I'm stuck.  Let's assume my first table exists in cols A and B and I'm trying to start the horizontal data sets in C2 and D2 so I've typed "Honda" in C1 and I've typed "Toyota" in D1.  I want to use C1 and D1 to look up a match in A and then return the values for each match from B.  I've been able to find a match as follows, but can't seem to get much further.  Have tried several different combos of things.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
=MATCH(C1,$A:$A,0)

=MATCH(D1,$A:$A,0)
```

With the above functions, C2 currently has a "2" which is correct and D2 has a "4" which is also correct, but I want the text of both of the models to appear, and not just the first model, but all models that match that make.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you could use the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions.

If your data was in A1:B5 you could use this formula in E1 to get the unique makes.

```swift
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$5))
```

To list the models for each make you could use this formula in E2 and copy it across.

```swift
=FILTER($B$2:$B$5, $A$2:$A$5=E$1)
```